# How to display image from API in swift?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, xcode, api

I want to be able to display the image sent by my `nodeJS` API (`http://my_api/getUserImg`) in Swift.
This specific route is returning an image like that :

```
fs.readFile('my_file.jpg', function(err,data) {
  if (err)
    res.json({success: false, message: err});
  res.send(data);`
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `NSURLSession` to get the `NSData` from your API. Then you can put that data into a `UIImage` and display it in a `UIImageView`.

Full Example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testImageView: UIImageView!

let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://my_api/getUserImg"){

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error in

        if let err = error {
            print("Error: \(err)")
            return
        }

        if let http = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if http.statusCode == 200 {
                let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.testImageView.image = downloadedImage
                })
            }
        }
   })
   task.resume()
}
```

[Example Project on GitHub](https://github.com/mreil617/SwiftExamples/tree/master/RemoteDataLoading)